# How to build your React component as a dependency library using Webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I created a small proof of concept React component and pushed it here -> https://github.com/lropero/poc

I'd like to be able to import this component within a different React project by doing: `npm install git+https://github.com/lropero/poc.git` and then `import Poc from 'poc'` and be able to render the component (i.e. `<Poc />`). The thing is **I'm getting React's invariant violation error #321** because I'm using hooks (useEffect in this example). I tried commenting this hook out and I'm able to see the `<p>TEST</p>` element rendered fine. I'm guessing it's a Webpack issue when building Poc's bundle?

Relevant files shown below (everything at https://github.com/lropero/poc):

`./src/index.jsx`:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('SUCCESS')
  }, [])
  return <p>TEST</p>
}

if (!process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
}

export default App
```

`./package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "poc",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Proof of concept importing React bundle.",
  "module": "./dist/bundle.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf dist && npx webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
    "clean": "rm -f npm-*.log && rm -f package-lock.json && rm -rf node_modules && npm cache verify",
    "nuke": "npm run clean && npm install",
    "start": "npx webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.4.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0"
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true
}
```

`./webpack.config.js` (`webpack.common.js` and `webpack.prod.js` merged together):

```
{
  entry: './src/index.jsx',
  mode: 'production',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    library: 'Poc',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      [name]: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to exclude `React` + `ReactDOM` out of your bundle file as you build with production mode.

As you publish your code as React component, apart from set `React` as peer dependency you have to set the `react` as externals to use the react at the consumer library.

Add more external property in your `webpack.prod.js`:

```
externals: {
  'react': {
    commonjs: 'react',
    commonjs2: 'react',
    amd: 'React',
    root: 'React'
  },
  'react-dom': {
    commonjs: 'react-dom',
    commonjs2: 'react-dom',
    amd: 'ReactDOM',
    root: 'ReactDOM'
  }    
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The configuration from tmhao will make your module build not work on Linux, it wont be able to find react because of case sensitive issues. Just a heads up, amd should be 'react'

```js
externals: {
  'react': {
    commonjs: 'react',
    commonjs2: 'react',
    amd: 'react',
    root: 'React'
  },
  'react-dom': {
    commonjs: 'react-dom',
    commonjs2: 'react-dom',
    amd: 'react-dom',
    root: 'ReactDOM'
  }    
}
```